# Changed motherboard, CPU and RAM -- now I get a reboot loop after selecting Debian from GRUB

Tags: debian, windows, troubleshooting

What I used to have:

- ASUS P8Z77-M motherboard
- Intel i7-3770K 3.5GHz Quad-core CPU
- 4 x 4GB RAM sticks -- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series, DDR3

What I have now:

- MSI Z170A motherboard
- Intel i7-6700 Quad-core CPU
- 4 X 4GB RAM sticks -- G.SKILL Ripjaws V series, DDR4

My video card is an EVGA GeForce GTX 960.

I have an SSD with Debian 8.2 Jessie, an SSD with Windows 10, and an HDD with no OS.

When I start my computer, the BIOS boots just fine, then the GRUB menu gives me three options as usual:

- Debian GNU/Linux
- Advanced options for GNU/Linux
- Windows boot loader

When I choose the first option, I get the following message:

```
Loading, please wait...
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean, 323042/14057462 files, 24103805/56225536 blocks
```

Then my PC reboots.

This happens when I choose the Windows option too. It gets to the Windows logo, then reboots.

If I choose the second option, then choose "Recovery mode," a bunch of output is printed, then the PC resets itself. This image shows the last lines printed before it reboots:
[image]

How do I fix everything so that I can boot back into Windows or Debian once more?

**ADDENDUM: I can load the Debian 8.2 Jessie Net Install CD. I can go to "Resuce Mode" and open a terminal as root user from there...**

Comment: Have you tried swapping SATA-connectors to change disk detection order? If so, does it make a difference?

Comment: Or start with single disk at first.

Comment: Tried both, makes no difference

Comment: Try running memtest to exclude hardware problems. It's available on several live distros, for example from http://www.finnix.org/.